# How do I create task_handle object as member of the class?

Tags: c++

In my Software I have a for loop which has very heavy process so I want to use parallel method such as `mask_task` to run this for loop in parallel.
I need to create an array of task handler in the header file and then use them in cpp file.
The MSDN definition of `make_task` is local and the return value is 'auto' so i can not use the MSDN.

This is what I am currently using successfully:

```
auto t1 = make_task([&]ParProcess(Input1,&Output1,&Output2);});
```

but I need to convert 't1' to the member of class and a pointer.
May anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee404732.aspx), `make_task` returns a `task_handle<Function>` where `Function` is the function type you pass in.

Lambdas have types that cannot be named, so your two options are to wrap the lambda in a `std::function`:

```
struct ClassContainingTask {
    ClassContainingTask(int Input1, int *Output1, int *Output2) :
        t1(std::function<void()>([&]{ParProcess(Input1,Output1,Output2);}))
    {}
    task_handle<std::function(void())> t1;
};
```

or to make your class a template and making the `task_handle` a template parameter:

```
template<typename F>
struct ClassContainingTask {
    ClassContainingTask(F &&f) : t1(std::forward<F>(f))
    {}

    task_handle<typename std::decay<F>::type> t1;
};

template<typename F>
ClassContainingTask<F>
make_ClassContainingTask_helper(F &&f) {
    return ClassContainingTask<F>(std::forward<F>(f));
}

//Call this to create the ClassContainingTask instantiated
//with the appropriate template parameter
auto make_ClassContainingTask = [](int Input1, int *Output1, int *Output2) {
    return make_ClassContainingTask_helper([&]{ParProcess(Input1,Output1,Output2);});
};
```

Comment: Thanks 'Mankarse'.i try to make task_handle a template parameter but vc++ get a lot of error. would you please write a example for this case ?